# mpfr_set_str don't give good value

Tags: c, mpfr

For a project in C, I try to use the [GNU MPFR Library](http://www.mpfr.org/).

But I don't understand the functioning of the *mpfr_printf* function.

For exemple for the code :

```
mpfr_t x;
mpfr_init( x );
mpfr_set_str( x, "213598703592091008239502270499962879705109534182641740644", 10, MPFR_RNDN);
mpfr_printf( "%.0RF\n", x );
mpfr_printf( "%.0RNf\n", x );
mpfr_printf( "%.0R*f\n", MPFR_RNDN, x );
```

Show for all *mpfr_printf* the value **213598703592090993136552875701722213572989498633163374592**

It's clearly not the same value... but I don't know why?

I can't use the [The GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library](https://gmplib.org/) because I need the function of MPFR like "log" and "exp".

I have also try differents *Rounding Modes* in place of "MPFR_RNDN" but none works.

Answer (score 0):

All three of those mpfr_printf statements are equivalent. (I assume you got them [from here](http://cs.swan.ac.uk/~csoliver/ok-sat-library/internet_html/doc/doc/Mpfr/3.0.0/mpfr.html/Formatted-Output-Functions.htm) )

```
mpfr_printf( "%.0RF\n", x );
```

Rounds to the nearest value (default)

```
mpfr_printf( "%.0RNf\n", x );
```

Rounds to nearest (because "RN")

```
mpfr_printf( "%.0R*f\n", MPFR_RNDN, x );
```

Rounds to nearest (because "MPFR_RNDN")

Answer (score 0):

From [GNU MPFR 4.0.1](http://www.mpfr.org/mpfr-current/mpfr.html):

```
 A floating-point number, or float for short, is an arbitrary precision
 significand (also called mantissa) with a **limited** precision exponent.
 The C data type for such objects is mpfr_t
 ....
 The precision is the **number of bits used to represent the significand**
 of a floating-point number;...
```

The 'mpfr' numbers are represented as float and have precision. You may read about floating number precision (the number of bits in the significant) on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic).

Each mpfr must be initialized with a precision by user. `mpfr_init` initialized number with a default precision. From manual: `The default precision is set to 53 bits initially`.
Use `mpfr_init2` function to set the precision (try to use it always). The following will run as expected, however you may run out of memory:

```
int main()
{
    mpfr_t x;
    mpfr_init2(x, 200);
    mpfr_set_str( x, "213598703592091008239502270499962879705109534182641740644", 10, MPFR_RNDN);
    mpfr_printf( "%.0RF\n", x );
    mpfr_printf( "%.0RNf\n", x );
    mpfr_printf( "%.0R*f\n", MPFR_RNDN, x );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you very much it helped me, I used mpz_sizeinbase (my_mpz, 2) to determine the number of bits to put in mpfr-init2 ()... 
I use big numbers as "unsigned long long int" ; I wanted to know if there was not another way to determine the number of bits, please?